# What is quiver momentum in plasma physics?

Tags: definition, plasma-physics

In plasma physics texts discussing dynamics of individual charged particles under electromagnetic fields, the term "quiver momentum" is frequently used, but I haven't seen a clear definition so far. So what is quiver momentum?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponderomotive_energy